# Widget used in Google Play Newsstand?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view

I am trying to implement a widget like **Google Play Newsstand** app but I am not able to make out which **collection** widget is used for providing **up/down scrolling buttons** for showing one item a time like this :

[image: Newsstand widget]

I think it's not a `Listview/Gridview` widget as they normally provide scrolling behaviour. Is it a `AdapterViewFlipper` widget? Or these are just custom buttons used in a collection widget?

Comment: i think it is Adapterviewflipper widget.https://github.com/arichiardi/ava-project this link helpful for you i think

Comment: Thanks @kishan, i"ll try the same.

Comment: @ruhcita happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use AndroidSlidingUpPanel

This library provides a simple way to add a draggable sliding up panel (popularized by Google Music and Google Maps) to your Android application.

You can visit this link :

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Hope its help

Comment: Thanks Fatah for the answer. As per [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections) , the type of collection widgets are ListView,GridView,StackView and AdapterViewFlipper so will this sample work with a list of data for widgets ?